# recording live video stream from tv card using ffmpeg in windows

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I want to capture thumbnail every 1 second from tv card(tv signal) using ffmpeg in windows.

first of all, to record live video from tv card, I tried below.

> ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="SKYTV HD USB Maxx Video Capture" -r 20 -threads 0 D://test.mkv

But it didn't work.
the Error message is

> "[dshow@000000000034d920] Could not run filter
>   video=SKYTV HD USB Maxx Video Capture: Input/output error"

I use the device called 'SKYTV HD USB Maxx Video Capture' for getting tv signal(TV card).

(people usually suggest "`ffmpeg -f oss -i dev/dsp -f video4linux2 -i dev/video0/tmp/out.mpg`" 
but I dont think it works at window. this is the error message i got: "`Unknown input format: 'video4linux2'`")

what should i do to record live video and get thumbnail every 1 second from tv card(tv signal) using ffmpeg in window?

Please help..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First be sure that the `video` label you use is really the label return by:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

More info [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow)
But another solution should be ti use the old **"Video For Windows" (VFW).**
To try that, list your device with:

```
ffmpeg -y -f vfwcap -i list
```

And use your device number as value of the `-i`option:

```
ffmpeg -y -f vfwcap -r 25 -i 0 out.mp4
```

And if finally you are able to record your stream, there is different options, but in your case everything is clear describe [here](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video)

```
ffmpeg -y -f vfwcap -r 25 -i 0 -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1 out%d.jpg
```

Comment: And, I want to ask one more question. I use TV card which can get many channels. But the way you suggest can not set the channels which I want to get. do you know how to set the channel?

Comment: No idea, but look at ffmpeg doc or fftv project!

Comment: OK ffmpeg crossbar support was added recently, so defaulting back to vfwcap should not be needed [it should work now without modification]. Cheers!